# Call a function inside resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm studying promises; can anybody explain me why this piece of code does not work is I call the 
function add() inside the resolve?

```
<script>
async function f() {

function add() {
  return 14+3;
}


  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{resolve(add)}, 3000); //this doesn't work
    setTimeout(()=>{resolve(14+3)}, 3000); // this works
  });

  let result = await promise;

  alert(result);

  alert ("END");
}

f();
</script>
```

Comment: `add` is a function, so with `resolve(add)`, the `result` turns into that function..?

Comment: You’re not calling the function.

Comment: Either `resolve(add())`, or `result()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resolve with value you actually returning value from promise. In your example you resolve with function in arguments, so your promise returns function(function add)

So modify line, 
`resolve(add);`
to 
`resolve(add());`